# How to make backend server of a Google OAuth App receive "Remove Access" event or other events such as "Account Disabled", "Token Revoked"

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

I'm developing a backend service to use Google OAuth Clients, I don't how to know whether refreshToken is revoked or not, and when the user's account is disabled/enabled.

There is a document of integration of RISC event push notifications.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#auth_token

but it doesn't mention how OAuth App uses it, no ideas about how to generate JWT token for OAuth2.0 Clients.
Do you have any ideas or experiences of receiving RISC events for a third party oauth App?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revoke a users authorization to your application you can use the [Revoke token endpoint](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke)

Just send the access token.

```
curl -H "Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke?token={token}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to get push notifications on server side when OAuth token manually revoked by user, to purge data and notify users on my app, rather than call API to revoke token.

Comment: @LeoPucciBr there is no push notification for when a user revokes your apps access.  The only way to know is the next time you try to use the token it wont work.

Comment: @DaImTo but here https://developers.google.com/identity/account-linking/unlinking#token_revocation_endpoint it says about a token revocation endpoint
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321715/missing-option-to-configure-revoke-token-url-in-google-actions-panel