# Missing option to configure revoke token URL in Google Actions panel

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

In the Google Actions panel we can enable account linking. We can also specify Authorization URL (*Endpoint for your sign-in web page that supports OAuth2 code or implicit flows*) and Token URL *(OAuth2 endpoint for token exchange*). [Endpoints configuration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxnW0.png)

I don't see any configuration options for Token revocation endpoint, and this possibility is described in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/account-linking/unlinking#token_revocation_endpoint

*If you support an OAuth 2.0 token revocation endpoint, your platform can receive notifications from Google. This lets you inform users of link state changes, invalidate a token, and cleanup security credentials and authorization grants.*

Where can I set Token revocation endpoint to receive requests when a user deletes a Google Account link directly in their account?

Comment: I am also looking for this answer

Comment: Did you ever find out how to configure this?